# Django REST framework hide a specific serializer field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to know how to hide a specific field in serializer(ModelSerializer)

Example

Models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hide_this_one = models.CharField(max_length=30) # hide this field
```

serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class BookApiView(views.APIView):
    template_name = 'book/create-book.html'
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer = BookSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer':serializer})
```

I want to hide the hide_this_one field when the serializer is rendered to HTML

And I need the hide_this_one field on the html but stay hidden(<input type="hidden" ......>)

Please tell me how to hide the label if you change the field in style.

Example:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hide_this_one = serializers.CharField(...., style={'input_type':'hidden'})

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try  ```fields =['author','title']```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exclude`

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hide_this_one = serializers.CharField(...., style={'input_type':'hidden'})

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ('hide_this_one', )
```

Comment: I need to hide this field(widget = forms.hiddeninput()) not to exclude it

Comment: class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hide_this_one = serializers.HiddenField(default="")

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("author", "title", "hide_this_one")